# Is the conference a scam?

Tags: conference

I have submitted a paper for a conference organized by the IRES. (details here: https://www.allconferencealert.com/event_detail.php?ev_id=80364) they accepted my paper within one day and instructed me to register. How will I know it is scam or not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that's a scam. Ask a senior researcher at your group for advise where to submit your work.

Comment: looks very shady. the website collects all kinds of unrelated logos to make it seem legit. this includes the logo of the social science research centre berlin (which has nothing to do with engineering) and even the library of the town of hamburg. by the way, allconferencealert.com seems to be fraudulent all the way down.

Comment: The details include *188th International Conference on . . .* As someone who's mostly used to major conferences being yearly (perhaps sometimes twice a year), "188th" certainly raises a red flag for me.

Comment: How many IRES conference papers have you cited?  How many IRES papers have the papers that you've cited cited?  How many IRES papers has your advisor cited?  If your answers to all three questions is "zero", it's not a good venue for your paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually conferences that are overly generic are a scam because anyone's work can fit in this category. Which field of engineering is this conference on? All engineering? This would hardly be an interesting conference to attend for engineers, because it would be very unlikely that someone else publishes in their specific field, on their topic or problem. There are conferences on sub-sub fields of engineering of more than a week in duration and this journal will cover any and all innovations in engineering in 2 days?

A good first start is to ask your supervisor or other professors in your field of study. Since your supervisor's name has to be on the paper alongside yours, they should guide you in this regard.

As a second filter, you should try and publish in a journal or conference that you cited often, or that published on work related to yours, as typically your own work would be a good fit there.

As a third filter, try and find papers that are published at this conference and see if they are any good, and if they all have the same style / formatting. I cant seem to find a template for this conference on their website, which is another red flag. Why would they allow everyone to just post in whatever format they choose?

Something odd, there is a gallery link to a generic gallery website (why would they have this unless it is a general catch all for a bunch of conferences), and none of the photos have any significant number of people in it. In the photos no one is smiling.

Finally, if your paper is accepted in 1 day or in a week, or in two weeks you know no academic or researcher looked at it. A good conference provides peer review feedback, typically of 3 reviewers, sometimes more. A response in a single day, guaranteed fake conference.

Random idea: Maybe we should have rubbish fake papers to submit to conferences before we submit our original work to test if it is a fake conference.